# Chax with Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos

Has anybody tried [Chax](http://www.ksuther.com/chax/) with Mac OS X Lion?

I got it to install perfectly, but I do not see a Chax tab in iChat preferences.

Comment: I was wondering the same. Nice question.

Comment: My favorite feature was to send a camera snapshot (even flipped correctly!) right from the menu. LOOOVE that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been in communication with the creator of Chax, and no, it doesn't work on Lion (it definitely works in Snow Leopard). He says he's working on it.

His site is [here](http://www.ksuther.com/contact/).

Addendum 9-11-11: The main awesomeness of Chax is the ability to auto-accept Screen Shares with certain people in your Buddy List... including yourself. For instance, if you travel with a laptop and suddenly need to get files from your Mac back home, you simply get a second iChat/AIM account for that laptop, set up Chax on the home Mac, set it up to autoaccept the laptop's account, and you can screen share automatically with your home Mac. I've come to completely rely on that weekly for the past couple years.

Comment: +1 for explaining "the main awesomeness of Chax" -- I'm going to try that out when Lion compatibility arrives.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't see Chax, it might not be compatible. That said, it really depends on what you intend to use Chax for. I suggest looking up the enhancements in the new iChat and seeing if your needs are covered there.

Comment: Many people use Chax for tabbed conversations etc, and this is now provided as standard.  It seems that Chax is not compatible, nor likely to be in the near future at least.  Are there other features of Chax that you want that are not provided by default, if so amend your question and people may be able to offer alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to take a look at this. this actually works very well, just like Chax. I love it!

http://scriptingosx.com/2010/11/ichat-notification-with-growl/

Comment: Big +1 to this.  This script is the only thing I've found that actually works in Lion.  It's simple to set up, just copy and paste.  Just keep in mind that for the file transfer notification, you'll need to change the text in the script, as Apple switched around the order of the words in Lion.

Comment: I don't have the reputation here yet to post my modification to the script linked above to make it play nice in Lion, but I posted it to the comments of the link above.

Comment: @juggleware I am not able to see your comment on the link above, and there is a mistake on the script somewhere, it doesn't run on my Lion. Would you mind posting your modifs here?

Comment: is it kosher to post code in the comments?

Answer (score 2):

There's a big ole notice up on the creator's site saying it's not compatible with Lion. [Looks like he's working on it though](http://www.ksuther.com/contact/).

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I Actually think that we lost Chax in Snow Leopard so it's possible that it just won't work in Lion either. Apple removed a few of the ways that Chax used to interact with iChat in Snow Leopard so unless the developer has found a way around them you're out of luck.

Comment: chax worked in Snow Leopard. It installs in Lion, and even prompts for my user password, but does not function beyond that. Hope a fix is coming.

Comment: Oh, I must have abandoned it before support was added for SL (damn my early adopting tendencies). My mistake